# Javascript Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I don't understand the error in the code below. I tried calling another class's function from another class. But I gives the error `error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_name' of undefined`

```js
class Person {
    constructor() {
        this._name = "Name-Person";
    }

    getName() {
        return this._name;
    }
}

class Test1 {
    constructor() {
        let p = new Person();
        new Test2(p.getName);
    }
}

class Test2 {
    constructor(getName) {
        console.log(getName());
    }
}

new Test1()
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When passing the function to `Test2` you need to bind `p` to the function

```
new Test2(p.getName.bind(p));
```

```js
class Person {
    constructor() {
        this._name = "Name-Person";
    }

    getName() {
        return this._name;
    }
}

class Test1 {
    constructor() {
        let p = new Person();
        new Test2(p.getName.bind(p));
    }
}

class Test2 {
    constructor(getName) {
        console.log(getName());
    }
}

new Test1()
```

Comment: Or use the arrow syntax: `new Test2()(()=>{p.getName()})`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [public class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields):

```js
class Person {
    constructor() {
        this._name = "Name-Person";
    }

    getName = () => {
        return this._name;
    }
}

class Test1 {
    constructor() {
        let p = new Person();
        new Test2(p.getName);
    }
}

class Test2 {
    constructor(getName) {
        console.log(getName());
    }
}

new Test1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing the function and not the entire class or its value, `_name` does not exist in the context of the Test2 constructor.

A couple of simple solutions is to either pass in the result of `getName()` to the constructor, or the entire class of Person.

```js
new Test2(p); // And in Test2 use p.getName()

// or

new Test2(p.getName()); // And in Test2 use the result
```